# bash + how to capture word from a long output

Tags: regex, language-agnostic

I have the following output from the following command

```
zookeeper-shell.sh 19.2.6.4  get /brokers/ids/1010
```

output is

```
Connecting to 19.2.6.4

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
{"listener_security_protocol_map":{"PLAINTEXT":"PLAINTEXT"},"endpoints":["PLAINTEXT://kafka1.lulu.com:6667"],"rack":"/default-rack","jmx_port":9997,"port":6667,"host":"kafka1.lulu.com","version":4,"timestamp":"1630507307906"}
```

The main target is to capture the machine name `kafka1` – from above output

So  I successes to do the following long command syntax

```
zookeeper-shell.sh 119.2.6.4  get /brokers/ids/1010 | sed s'/\/\// /g' | sed s'/:/ /g' | sed s'/,/ /g' | sed s'/"/ /g' | sed s'/\./ /g'| awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' | grep -i kafka | sort | uniq
```

and the results is:  ( as expected results )

```
kafka1
```

**the case is that I feel bad with my approach** , its too long and not so elegant

can we get suggestion ( with awk/sed/perl one liner ) , that are much better from my syntax?

Comment: You don't need multiple `sed` commands. `sed -e 's/x/y/g' -e 's/a/b/g' ...`

Comment: Also `sed -e 's/[:,."]/ /g'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown samples, attempts please try following `awk` code. Since I don't have zookeeper command with me, I had written this code and tested it as per your shown output only.

```
zookeeper-shell.sh 19.2.6.4  get /brokers/ids/1010 | 
awk '
/WatchedEvent state/{
  found=1
  next
}
found && match($0,/"PLAINTEXT:\/\/[^:]*/){
  print substr($0,RSTART+13,RLENGTH-13)
}
'
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above `awk` code.

```
awk '                                         ##Starting awk program from here.
/WatchedEvent state/{                         ##Checking condition if line contains WatchedEvent state
  found=1                                     ##Then set found to 1 here.
  next                                        ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
found && match($0,/"PLAINTEXT:\/\/[^:]*/){    ##Checking condition if found is SET then match regex "PLAINTEXT:\/\/[^:]* in match function of awk.
  print substr($0,RSTART+13,RLENGTH-13)       ##Printing sub string of matched regex used in match function above.
}
'
```

Answer (score 4):

The text you want to parse is JSON so use a JSON-aware tool like `jq` for the bulk of the work, e.g. using `cat file` since I don't have the command you use to produce output:

```
$ cat file | jq -Rr 'fromjson? | .endpoints[]'
PLAINTEXT://kafka1.lulu.com:6667

$ cat file | jq -Rr 'fromjson? | .endpoints[]' | awk -F'[/.]' '{print $3}'
kafka1
```

Answer (score 2):

Using perl, you can do:

```
$zookeeper_command | perl -MJSON::PP=decode_json -wnE'/^\{"/ or next; $j = decode_json($_); ($s) = (split /\./, $j->{host})[0]; say $s'
```

detailing the command:

- `-MJSON::PP=decode_json`  => imports `decode_json` from `JSON::PP` module (it's a core module.
- `/^\{"/ or next;`  => skip lines doesn't look like a json string.
- `$j = decode_json($_);`  => store into `$j` a data structure fom json string.
- `($s) = (split /\./, $j->{host})[0];` => split string `kafka1.lulu.com` and store in `$s` only first portion.

It can also be written in a shorter form (and less readable too):

```
$zookeeper_command | perl -MJSON::PP=decode_json -wnE'say decode_json($_)->{host}=~s/\..*$//r if/^\{"/'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use following script to filter out data of interest, what would allow you to avoid typing long command lines.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use JSON;

my $data;

while( <> ) {
    next unless /^\{.*?\}$/;   # skip all but JSON string
    
    my $data = from_json($_);  # restore data structure
    my $host = (split('\.',$data->{host}))[0]; # extract info of interest
    
    say $host;                 # output it
}
```

Run as `zookeeper-shell.sh 19.2.6.4  get /brokers/ids/1010 | script.pl`.

Note: make script executable `chmod +x script.pl` and store it in your `$HOME/bin` directory which add in your variable `$PATH`.